# ARKit – Are the values entered for Reference Image dimensions important?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

In ARKit, I am using the height and width of reference images (as entered by me into XCode in the AR Resource Group) to overlay planes of the same size onto matched images.  Regardless of whether I enter accurate reference image dimensions, ARKit accurately overlays the plane onto the real world (i.e., the plane correctly covers the matched image in the ARSCNView).

If I understand correctly, estimatedScaleFactor tells me the difference between the true size of the reference image and the values I entered in the Resource Group.

My question is, if ARKit is able to figure the true size of the object shown in the reference image, when/why would I need to worry about entering accurate height and width values.

(My reference images are public art and accurately measuring them is sometimes difficult.)

Does ARKit have to work harder, or are there scenarios where I would stop getting good results without accurate Reference Image measurements?

ADDITIONAL INFO: As a concrete example, if I was matching movie posters, I would take a photo of the poster, load it into an AR Resource Group, and arbitrarily set the width to something like one meter (allowing Xcode to set the other dimension based on the proportions of the image).

Then, when ARKit matches the image, I would put a plane on it in renderer(_:didAdd:for:)

```swift
let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
    height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.planeColor
        
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

node.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

This appears to work as desired--the plane convincingly overlays the matched image--in spite of the fact that the dimensions I entered for the reference image are inaccurate. (And yes, estimatedScaleFactor does give a good approximation of by how much my arbitrary dimensions are off by.)

So, what I am trying to understand is whether this will break down in some scenarios (and when, and what I need to learn to understand why!). If my reference image dimensions are not accurate, will that negatively impact placing planes or other objects onto the node provided by ARKit?

Put another way, if ARKit is correctly understanding the world and reference images without accurate ref image measurements, does that mean I can get away with never entering accurate measurements for ref images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/2941027-physicalsize) suggests:

> The default value of [estimatedScaleFactor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimageanchor/3075552-estimatedscalefactor) (a factor between the initial size and the estimated physical size) is 1.0, which means that a version of this image that ARKit recognizes in the physical environment exactly matches its reference image physicalSize.
> Otherwise, ARKit automatically corrects the image anchor's transform when estimatedScaleFactor is a value other than 1.0. This adjustment in turn, corrects ARKit's understanding of where the image anchor is located in the physical environment.

```
var estimatedScaleFactor: CGFloat { get }
```

For more precise scale of 3D model you need to measure your real-world image and when AR app will be running, ARKit measures its observable reference image. `ARImageAnchor` stores a value of `estimatedScaleFactor` property, thus ARKit registers a difference in scale factor, and then it applies the new scale to 3D model and you model becomes bigger or smaller, that `estimatedScaleFactor` is for.

However, there's an automatic methodology:

> To accurately recognize the position and orientation of an image in the AR environment, ARKit must know the image's physical size. You provide this information when creating an AR reference image in your Xcode project's asset catalog, or when programmatically creating an ARReferenceImage.
>
> When you want to recognize different-sized versions of a reference image, you set `automaticImageScaleEstimationEnabled` to true, and in this case, ARKit disregards physicalSize.

```
var automaticImageScaleEstimationEnabled: Bool { get set }
```

Comment: I guess I am wondering if/when my experience will break down without accurate reference image dimensions. Let me add a bit to my question...

Comment: Your experience will not break down, it might rather be inaccurate if you don't give a physicalSize.

Comment: Andy, thanks a bunch for all the work you put into answers. I have learned TONS from your contributions.